# MS Access VBA: Creating Excel Workbook with multiple Worksheets

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I can create a workbook that contains a single worksheet using the following code:

```
'Create Custom Excel Report
Set XL = New Excel.Application
XL.Visible = True
Set WB = XL.Workbooks.Add
Set WKS = WB.Worksheets(1)
WKS.Name = "Fred"

'Set Report Headers
WKS.Cells(2, 1).value = "Name"
WKS.Cells(2, 2).value = "Address"
WKS.Cells(2, 3).value = "Hat Size"
```

How can I create a workbook that has 3 worksheets?  How do I set the values for the individual worksheets?

Comment: Use [Worksheets.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/sheets-add-method-excel) method. After 2010, every workbook has at least one worksheet (so you never added it to begin).

Comment: So would I just set a new variable like:
`Set WKS2 = WB.Worksheets.Add`

Comment: Correct. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes.  that was the answer.  Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The workbook starts with one sheet.  You can append a sheet and name it via a line like this:

```
WB.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Fred"
```

You can assign a variable on creation, or you can reference the new sheet be name: E.g., `WB.Sheets("Fred")`